# Query AWS ELB TARGET GROUP Target Health State and perform function depending on some condition

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, shell, jq, amazon-elb

I have a requirement where I need to invoke some function or lets say command depending on the `TargetHealth` state for the targets within a target group in AWS. I perform the below to get the list of targets in the target group :-

```
aws elbv2 --region us-east-1 describe-target-health --target-group-arn=******

{
    "TargetHealthDescriptions": [{
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "initial",
                "Reason": "Elb.RegistrationInProgress",
                "Description": "Target registration is in progress"
            }
        },
        {
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "unhealthy",
                "Reason": "Target.Timeout",
                "Description": "Connection to target timed out"
            }
        },
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80",
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        },
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80",
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        },
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80",
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        },
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80",
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        },
        {
            "HealthCheckPort": "80",
            "Target": {
                "Id": "***",
                "Port": 80
            },
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "healthy"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Once i get the JSON reponse for all the targets i want to do a If condition to ensure only when number of targets > 4 and all of them are healthy, then do xyz... So say something like

```
if ( countoftarget >4 && alltargethasstate == healthy) then 
    echo "*****" 
else 
    sleep 2 minutes and keep checking the loop
```

Is there a way to use `jq` to parse the value for state for all targets and implement a shell script to perform this loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small snipped that will help you achieve this without `jq`.

```
HEALTHY_COUNT=`aws elbv2 --region us-east-1 describe-target-health --target-group-arn=******* \
--query 'TargetHealthDescriptions[?TargetHealth.State==\`healthy\`].[Target.Id]' --output text | wc -l`
echo $HEALTHY_COUNT

if [ $HEALTHY_COUNT -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "All izzz well!!!"
else 
    echo "Recheck how many healthy"
fi
```

The interesting part here is the `query` that is used to control the output of the was cli. See the [aws cli documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html) around this, particularly the section 
"How to Filter the Output with the --query Option" . The query option is based on [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) that is documented here and is pretty nifty while working with the AWS CLI.

Comment: I want to do something similar but i want to keep looping to check if all instances in target group are healthy and then i want to proceed. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential advantages of using jq here is that you can easily avoid multiple calls to aws.

```
[.TargetHealthDescriptions[]
| select(.TargetHealth.State == "healthy")]
| . as $targets # in case you want to do something with them if the counting condition is satisfied
| length | if . > 4 then "found \(.) targets" else empty end
```